# App crashes with: startRunning may not be called between calls to beginConfiguration and commitConfiguration?

Tags: swift, xcode, avcapturesession

I am working on an app that is using a pod named WeScan (see their [github](https://github.com/WeTransfer/WeScan)).

After setting everything up and adding the correct items to my info.plist file my app keeps crashing.

The error is:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException', reason: '*** -[AVCaptureSession startRunning] startRunning may not be called between calls to beginConfiguration and commitConfiguration' "

Here is the code from the pod that I think is causing the problem:

```
init?(videoPreviewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer) {
self.videoPreviewLayer = videoPreviewLayer
super.init()

captureSession.beginConfiguration()
captureSession.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSession.Preset.photo

photoOutput.isHighResolutionCaptureEnabled = true

let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true

guard let inputDevice = AVCaptureDevice.default(for: AVMediaType.video),
    let deviceInput = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: inputDevice),
    captureSession.canAddInput(deviceInput),
    captureSession.canAddOutput(photoOutput),
    captureSession.canAddOutput(videoOutput) else {
        let error = ImageScannerControllerError.inputDevice
        delegate?.captureSessionManager(self, didFailWithError: error)
        return
}

captureSession.addInput(deviceInput)
captureSession.addOutput(photoOutput)
captureSession.addOutput(videoOutput)

videoPreviewLayer.session = captureSession
videoPreviewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravity.resizeAspectFill

videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "video_ouput_queue"))

captureSession.commitConfiguration()
}

// MARK: Capture Session Life Cycle

/// Starts the camera and detecting quadrilaterals.
internal func start() {
    let authorizationStatus = AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(for: AVMediaType.video)

    switch authorizationStatus {
    case .authorized:
        self.captureSession.startRunning()
        isDetecting = true
    case .notDetermined:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(for: AVMediaType.video, completionHandler: { (_) in
           DispatchQueue.main.async { [weak self] in
                self?.start()
            }
        })
    default:
        let error = ImageScannerControllerError.authorization
        delegate?.captureSessionManager(self, didFailWithError: error)
    }
}

internal func stop() {
    captureSession.stopRunning()
}

internal func capturePhoto() {
    let photoSettings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    photoSettings.isHighResolutionPhotoEnabled = true
    photoSettings.isAutoStillImageStabilizationEnabled = true

    if let photoOutputConnection = self.photoOutput.connection(with: .video) {
        photoOutputConnection.videoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientation(deviceOrientation: UIDevice.current.orientation) ?? AVCaptureVideoOrientation.portrait
    }
```

Comment: Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Comment: Everything looks great sorry about that!

Comment: Dont worry about that, simply do better next time ;-)

Answer (score 4):

Try placing the statement `captureSession.commitConfiguration()`
outside the guard block. It's because the commit must be done at the same level as the `beginConfiguration()`

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this issue: it started happening out of the blue when I was working on a completely different part of the app.

Deleting it and reinstalling it seems to have solved it.